# Is it possible to see which modules grants access rights?

Tags: 9

Working on a Drupal 9 website the module Permissions by term gives an unexpected behaviour.

Trying to find the problem I got stuck. I think there might be another module overwriting the permissions. But I can’t find out which one.

Is there a way to see which module grants what right to a node/user?

Or is there another step I should do to debug these node permissions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess looking at the `node_access` table in the database is not exactly helpful, but everything relating to grants is in there, including the grants from "Permissions by Term". If that doesn't help, I'd start digging through [NodeAccessControlHandler](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeAccessControlHandler.php/class/NodeAccessControlHandler/9.3.x), to understand where it goes wrong.

Comment: In case you didn't look at that yet, this might also help to understand the control flow and see what to watch out for: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/9.3.x

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help it was super informative! I found out that the Permissions by Entity module was creating the problem. Since I wasn't using it I could just uninstall it and all is working like expected now.